# Is Ransack has a way to implement token search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack, meta-search

Now I have `search_field`

```
= f.search_field :name_cont
```

I want to create a list of extra words(tokens) that will show a different query.

For example, if I type `John` it will show all Johns, but if I type `[]` it will show all users without a name.

One more:
`@` - will means users with a name.

New implementation also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, you can modify the search params according to any logic you like. E.g., assuming your search params are saved in a `@search_params` (replace with whatever var has your search params, e.g. `params[:q]`):

```
if @search_params[:name_cont] == "[]"
  @search_params[:name_blank] = true
  @search_params.delete(:name_cont)
end
if @search_params[:name_cont] == "@"
  @search_params[:name_present] = true
  @search_params.delete(:name_cont)
end
```